# How to use NestJS OpenAPI generator with middleware ExpressJS Response and locals?

Tags: express, nestjs, middleware, nestjs-swagger

I am using the NestJS middleware to inject some information in my response as locals for my controller. This happens like the following:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    // do some stuff
    res.locals.foo = "bar";
    next();
  }
}
```

In my controller I am doing the following:

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from '@/user/user.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Response as r } from 'express';

@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get('/')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  helloWorld(@Response() res: r) {
    res.status(200).send({ hello: r.locals.foo });
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that I want to return actually a Promise instead of letting `.send(...)` to handle this. The reason why is I am using the [OpenAPI NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters) generator mentioned here.

Notice that I am using `Response` from express (as `r`) to access locals. The challenge here is that if I don't use `r` but I would use the `nestjs/common` `Response` I am not able to access locals since it's not a variable.

Anyone solution around this? I read about [decorators](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators), I am wondering whether that's the only solution.

I am 100% sure that the middleware fires off as well since I am getting "bar" as expected from the middleware.

Thanks!